# How to add a using directive outside a namespace using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, namespaces, roslyn

I have a CSharpSyntaxRewriter that adds a new using directive to my file:-

```
public class AddUsingDirective : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitNamespaceDeclaration(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        // this adds the using directive inside the namespace not outside
        node = node.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("MyCompany.MyProject.DataAccessLayer.Abstractions"))).NormalizeWhitespace();

        return base.VisitNamespaceDeclaration(node);
    }
}
```

The problem is that is adds the new using directive *inside* the namespace but I want to add it to the other existing namespaces *above* the namespace declaration. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Once you've got the `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` it's too late -- the only thing you can change is the namespace declaration, and you want to change something outside of the namespace declaration. You need to be editing the `CompilationUnit`, [see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzhgHwAEAmARgFgAoagO2wFsZcAHbMGAAgDEIJqA3tU4jORAMxiSnAMLDRQqqM4BfaiqA)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public override SyntaxNode VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
{
    // this adds the using directive inside the namespace not outside
    node = node.AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("MyCompany.MyProject.DataAccessLayer.Abstractions"))).NormalizeWhitespace();

    return base.VisitNamespaceDeclaration(node);
}
```